# Problem retrieving data from Firestore Database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from a collection in my firestore database. But when print the retrieved data, it doesn't conform to the format I expected.

Here is my code to retrieve the data below :

```
 let db = Firestore.firestore()

    func loadEvents() -> [Event] {
        var events = [Event]()
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        db.collection("Events").addSnapshotListener { QuerySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = QuerySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            for doc in documents {
                let dict = doc.data()
                if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) {
                    let event = try? decoder.decode(Event.self, from: data)
                    events.append(event!)
                    print(events) // Prints stuff like [Envy.Event] ...
                }
            }
//            let events = documents.map {$0.data()}
            }
        return events
    }
```

On reaching the `print(events)` it prints stuff like `[Envy.Event]
[Envy.Event, Envy.Event]
[Envy.Event, Envy.Event, Envy.Event]
[Envy.Event, Envy.Event, Envy.Event, Envy.Event]` which is not suitable data format for manipulation. I don't even understand this format; Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

you are printing it wrong . you are printing the whole model class you created you need to refer the object inside the class for eg.

```
print(events.name) // use the object name you have in your class
print(events.location) // use the object name you have in your class
```

To add the data into array
Example Code:

```
db.collection("Events").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let list = Event(name: document.get("yourKeyName") as? String,location: document.get("yourAnotherKeyName") as? String)

                    events.append(list)
                    print(event.name)
                    print(event.location)

                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand this answer. I am trying to append them to the events array

Comment: & events is an array so the attributes can only be accessed by looping via

Comment: I have added the sample code above which may help you out. how to get the data from firestore which i use.

Comment: Your code is possibly correct but deviates from mine because I use a codable model class to decode the data from Firestore

Comment: I think so even though you have codeable classes, it should have init methods and when you will call a class it will automatically fetch the variables you created in model class. may be you should try it and let me know as well :)

Comment: Yes I am aware .. Anyways if the problem persist I might end up using init methods

Comment: Your solution gives me an empty array